# $ \text{If } f,g \in D(U) \implies \alpha f + \beta g \in D(U)(\alpha f + \beta g)'(x)=\alpha f'(x) + \beta g'(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

**Prove:** $f,g$ are differentiable functions on open set $U \implies \alpha f + \beta g$ is differentiable on $U$ as well. Furthermore, $(\alpha f + \beta g)'(x)=\alpha f'(x) + \beta g'(x)$.

**Proof:**

We will use the following functions to prove this:

$$L(u,v):=\alpha u + \beta v$$

We note that $L$ is clearly linear.

$$F: x \mapsto(f(x),g(x))$$

$F$ is differentiable because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are too.

$$h:=L \circ F$$

$$h: x\mapsto_{F} (f(x),g(x)) \mapsto_{L} \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) $$

A result from the composition of two differentiable function theorem, we see that

$$\begin{aligned}
h'(x)&=L'(F(x))F'(x)\\
&= L(F'(x)) \\
&=L(f'(x),g'(x)) \\
&= \alpha f'(x)+ \beta g'(x)
\end{aligned}$$

My thoughts: I know that the derivatives of $L(x)$ is $L$ if it is a linear function, and that $F'(x)=(f'(x),g'(x))$ what I don't understand is just this transition:

> $$...=L'(F(x))F'(x)=L(F'(x))=...$$

Comment: I made some serious edits to improve the readability of your question. Please ensure that I didn't fundamentally change the meaning of anything you previously wrote.

Comment: It is imo easier to work directly from the definition of the derivative namly $f$ is differantiable at $a$ if there exist a linear map $Df$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left||f(x+h) - f(a) - Df(h)\right||}{||h||} = 0$. Then the triangle inequality is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting your original proof mainly due to poor notation. Because you have defined $L$ as a function of two variables, it doesn't make sense to consider $L'$, but rather $\nabla L$. It is also important to note that $F$ takes one variable $x$ to two variables $(f,g)$. Therefore, $F'(x) \in U \times U$.

Revisiting the proof, it might make more sense to see it written as:

$$\begin{aligned}
h'(x) &= \nabla L(F(x))^T F'(x)\\
&= (\alpha, \beta)^T (f'(x), g'(x))\\
&= \alpha f'(x) + \beta g'(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, $h$ is differentiable and its derivative matches the expectation.

Comment: I see, never mind,  that was a very small detail , I thank you for pointing that out.